# Change the length of multicol to page, not amount of text

Tags: multicol

I'm writing a document using the multicol package, combined with tcolorbox. What I would like to do (and am wondering whether it is possible or not) is to write my code so that my multicol adjusts to page and not to the amount of content that is inside (cf figure).

[image: illustration of what I would like to get]

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

% [... some appearance code]

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!15!white,colframe=red!15!white]
        colorbox's text content
    \end{tcolorbox}
    % ... other colorboxes
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \begin{multicols*} --- but note that there are limitiations to how well tcolorbox works with multicol in the first place, because both try altering the page building algorithm --- see notes in tcolorbox manual.